# Ubuntu 20.04 no sound/audio

Tags: sound

I added myself to the audio group but still cannot get any audio out of the speakers.  I've tried most every suggestion to no avail, updates, etc. I double checked all applications controlling audio and none were muted.

I'm running a two year old OMEN laptop by HP.  Audio/sound works fine on the Windows side. I'm trying to quickly ween myself off Windows, but I have to have audio.  When I play music I can see that it is playing by activity on the horizontal meter under Settings – sound – output.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.  Scott

These details might help

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller (rev 31) 00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 0):

A fluke.  After I installed WINE 5.0 the sound/audio worked.  It must have installed some audio drivers Ubuntu was lacking?  Go figure.  Never the less I'm pleased.

Comment: No, not a fluke. Wine has nothing to to with pulseaudio, you cured a symptom, not the cause. I assume the installation rather changed your default card & output